# Need help understanding this DOUBLE SUMMATION problem?

Tags: optimization, summation

I came across this minimization problem while reading about the travelling salesman problem. The author urged us to frame it as an assignment problem (which is quite beyond my understanding too!) and went on to show us this formula
$$ z = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n d_{ij} x_{ij} $$
subject to
$$ \sum_{j=1}^n x_{ij} = 1\quad i=1,2,...n$$
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n x_{ij} = 1\quad j=1,2,...n$$
where $x_{ij} = 0\;$or $\;1$.

Please help me understand what this means conceptually. Thank you !

Comment: Write it down explicitly for $n=2$, i.e., without the $\sum$ symbol. Then you'll understand it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Miller%E2%80%93Tucker%E2%80%93Zemlin_formulation

Comment: +1 to the query, from (-1) back to (0).  While I normally don't object to downvoting a query where no work is shown, I don't like downvoting a query where the user is having trouble interpreting the query.  This is (at least somewhat) an interpretation issue.

Comment: In addition to the wikipedia article comment/linked by mavavilj, see also [Latin Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square), to help your visualization.  This query is a **variation** of Latin Squares, in that in each row and column, there is only a single $(1)$ entry, with all of the other entries equal to $(0)$.

Comment: Thank you @mavavilj for bringing the Wikipedia article to my notice.

Comment: Thank you for being kind @user2661923... I am new to the site and still learning a lot of stuff. Seeing the downvote was a little bit discouraging but I am glad that you helped me out :)